# RadioButton Text Alignment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, radio-button

I'm having trouble aligning text on the same line of a RadioButton in Android Studio.

Here is what I have...

[Application Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksb0T.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking

Comment: I want the text in a RadioButton to be on the same line as the button itself when I'm in the application. Right now, because the text is really long, the text starts one line above the radiobutton as shown above. Does this make sense?

Comment: Please post example XML layout.

Comment: You mean the radio button is vertically centred to the text?

Comment: the radio is simply centered within the text. That's normal, and that's what users expect. (the subtitle, on the other hand, looks like an editable text. you should change the style.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Try this out,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="male"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:text="besides"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, but how do i make that text appear on the same line where the button is shown? Some of the texts are really long and they start one line above where the button is (please see the question). I want to adjust the text to start on the same line as the RadioButton.